# foreach with 2 statement

Tags: c#, foreach

hi i wanna create a foreach with 2 statement like this

```
foreach (CSheet mySheet in mySheets && CSheet nameQuiz in nameQuizs ) {
    //problem if i just used one statement in foreach i can't give property 'name' to  
            nameQuiz...so it's limited like this
    oSheet = mySheet.name.toString(); 

    //i wanna make nameQuiz have property name too like mysheet
    oSheet = mySheet.name.toString();
    oName = nameQuiz.name.toString();
}
```

this is my CSheets

```
public class CSheet
{
    public string name;
    public CCell[] cells;
}
```

mysheets & nameQuizs is array
any idea?

---

artur

```
public static string exportToExcel(string fileName, CSheet[] mySheets, CSheet[] nameQuizs)
```

based on that code mySheets & nameQUizs related or not? how can i know if they related?

Comment: Can you explain what would do your loop,  step by step.

Comment: @katik On your "artur" edit: Erm ... if *you* don't know how `mySheets` and `nameQuizs` are related in some way, who would know? *You're* the one who's writing the code, so what's your intention? Are they in some way related? Why do you want to loop over both of them at the same time? What's the logic behind your code?

Comment: actually this project not i create from zero...i just fix any bug appear so i'm not understand well almost part of this code and this is first project C# i handle so i'm still learning...for your second question because if i create different loop...the result really differant from i want

Comment: @katik: I know. I was just trying to tell you that *you* as the developer should be the one who knows how parts of your code are related. So the answer to the question *based on that code `mysheets` & `nameQUizs` related or not?* is *No*, because they are just parameters to a method. From that declaration you can't tell the semantics. The answer to the question *How can I know if they related?* is: *Because you're the developer*. And how could you possibly fix bugs without even knowing how the sofware works?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar hm...i guess u're right
i will try to understand code of my project first
thanks for u suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do it this way. You could do it with one `for` loop, however:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(mySheets.Count, nameQuizs.Count); i++)
{
    CSheet mySheet = i < mySheets.Count ? mySheets[i] : null;
    CSheet nameQuiz = i < nameQuizs.Count ? nameQuizs[i] : null;

    oSheet = mySheet != null ? mySheet.name : String.Empty;
    oName = nameQuiz != null ? nameQuiz.name : String.Empty;
}
```

In acse your `mySheets` and `nameQuizs` lists are in fact arrays, you need to replace `Count` by `Length`.

Also, you don't need `name.ToString();`, as the `name` member is a `String` already.

Comment: Theoretically, `mySheets` or `nameQuizs` could be any kind of `IEnumerable` where getting a `Count` (or `Length`) could be difficult.

Comment: That, on the one hand, is true, on the other hand let's just hope for the best :-) I was just making a suggestion.

Comment: i got error Error 'Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group''

Comment: nameQuizs & mySheets are array..so is this way will work?

Comment: As I said already in my answer: If `nameQuizs` and `mySheets` are arrays, use `.Length` instead of `.Count`.

Comment: i already use .length but still get that error

Comment: OK, are we talking about the `<` in the `for` condition, or are we talking about the `<` in the ternary operator statements? Either way, please post the three  lines as you're using them now.

Comment: '<' in  CSheet mySheet = i < mySheets.Count ? mySheets[i] : null;  && CSheet nameQuiz = i < nameQuizs.Count ? nameQuizs[i] : null;

Comment: i forget to change that .count in there..i just change in 'for'...thanks now worked correctly

Answer (score 4):

You can [zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) two sequences (i.e. take corresponding items from both sequences):

```
foreach (var item in mySheets.Zip(nameQuizs, (s,nq) => new { mySheet = s, nameQuiz = nq }))
{
     oSheet = item.mySheet.name;    
     oSheet = item.mySheet.name;
     oName = item.nameQuiz.name;    
}
```

UPDATE: Thus you are using .NET 3.5 Zip extension is not available. But you can write your own:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TFirst> firstSource, 
    IEnumerable<TSecond> secondSource,
    Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> selector)
{
    using(var firstIterator = firstSource.GetEnumerator())
    using(var secondIterator = secondSource.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while(firstIterator.MoveNext() && secondIterator.MoveNext())
            yield return selector(firstIterator.Current, secondIterator.Current);
    }  
}
```

Comment: +1 Damn, again too late.

Comment: i got error 'systemArray does not contain a definition for zip' sory forget to write mySheets & nameQuizs is array before

Comment: @katik add `System.Linq` namespace using to your code file. Zip is extension method defined in that namespace

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy i still get same error even after add system.linq...i used framework 3.5 it's maybe give more hint

Comment: @katik LINQ is available in .NET Framework 3.5 what kind of error do you have?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy same error as when i not use Linq 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Zip' and no extension method 'Zip' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
'

Comment: @katik my bad, Zip was added in Framework 4.0 you can create your own extension for 3.5

Comment: hm..it's way i can't used it, i will try this way when i upgrade my project to framework 4.0

Answer (score 2):

If mySheets and nameQuizs are related you can put them together in a dictionary, 
`Dictionary<CSheet, CSheet>` and enumerate over that.

Alternatively use a for loop and an index of each element.

Answer (score 1):

If you want loop through while elements exists from both use this:

```
var mySheetsEnum = mySheets.GetEnumerator();
var nameQuizsEnum = nameQuizs .GetEnumerator();

while(mySheetsEnum.MoveNext() && nameQuizsEnum.MoveNext())
{
   ...
}
```

else you can use `||` instead of `&&`.

Comment: Btw that is exactly what happens in ZipIterator :) Also its better to wrap enumerators into using statements

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Fully agree.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this into one loop quite elegantly by using the [`Zip` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
foreach (var item in mySheets.Zip(nameQuizs, (s, q) => Tuple.Create(s, q)))
{
    var mySheet = item.Item1;
    var nameQuiz = item.Item2;
}
```

*Instead of a `Tuple`, an anonymous type is perhaps a better solution. See [Sergey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21450863/17713).*

What it does, basically, is that it iterates over to sequences and zip-merges the next element of each collection with one another. Typically you'd then merge them somehow, or copy them into a `Tuple` or any custom object.

Although the metaphor does not fit perfectly, you might think of two motorway lanes merging into one, where a concept of zip-merge applies to. However, here we get pairs of cars instead of one long line.

Comment: Are properties from tuple look more elegant than named properties from anonymous type?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Nope, I think your solution is better. Saw your answer just after I posted mine.

Comment: OK :) That's my personal dislike for tuples in C#